# Open multiple tabs in the same browser by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to open multiple tab in the main browser:
Here is my code:

```
    function openSM()
    {
        window.open("http://www.google.com","_blank");
        window.open("http://www.yahoo.com","_blank");
        window.open("http://www.bing.com","_blank");
    }
...
<div onClick="openSM()"> This is a div </div>
```

But only the first window open in new tab, the other windows open in a new browser.
What I should do to open every page in the same browser?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Which browser would that be? I'd imagine popup blockers would prevent opening more than one in most browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have no control over this so you will not be able to force a new tab to open programmatically. It's the browser that controls that feature, which can generally be configured by users.

It could only be forced if you have control over the client's browser configuration and/or can install extensions in the client's browser (often the case in intranets)

Answer (score 2):

I had done similar work, but didn't get success using simple javascript on page. So I create an extension and then the same code worked, you need a little modification in that:

```
    var urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.bing.com"];

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        var url = urls.pop();
        if(!!url) {
            window.open(url);
        }
        else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 100);
```

Hope this work for you too.

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that should be considered correct

Comment: @BenPetersen That solution is just plain wrong. If I configure my browser to open new windows rather than tabs window.open will open a new browser window, not a tab. Like I said, there's nothing you can do about it unless you have control over the client's browser configuration which is not the case on Internet (but could be in Intranets).

Comment: It's not because that code opened up new tabs in your browser that this solution works according to the question.